# Average of columns where number is not null

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, calculated-column

I am completely stuck on pretty trivial matter. I have columns

```
[ResponseTimeNumber],[CommunicationNumber],[PriceQualityNumber],[ResponsivenessNumber], [CompetenceNumber],[CommunicationNumber],[MeetDeadlineNumber]
```

Posissble values are 100, 66, 33, 0 and "" <- empty. How can I sum them and divide by those which are not empty.

For example: **column1 = 66, column2 = 0, column3 = ""**. Therefore in my calculated new column will be value: **33**

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this question depends on where you need the value. If you would like to show in in an app, it is rather easy to get (compute) it via JavaScript + Client Object Model / REST. If it needs to be displayed in a web part, it is even easier to get the value calculated on the server side.

If what you need is a value in the summary row of the list view, you have to customize the XSL files (main.xsl and vwstyles.xsl) used to display the XsltListVieWebPart. You find several examples for that [here](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/category/views/).

BTW, which version of SharePoint you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following formula in your calculated column:

```
=SUM([CommunicationNumber],[CompetenceNumber],[MeetDeadlineNumber],[PriceQualityNumber],[ResponseTimeNumber],[ResponsivenessNumber])/COUNT([CommunicationNumber],[CompetenceNumber],[MeetDeadlineNumber],[PriceQualityNumber],[ResponseTimeNumber],[ResponsivenessNumber])
```

You didn't specify what should be displayed when all fields have blank "" value.